# What does the output of a convolutional layer actually mean?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, convolution

I am trying to learn about convolutional neural nets and I was watching this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FmpDIaiMIeA

I was under the impression that when a filter was convolved around an input, the output at each point represented how closely the feature matched the input.

However in this video at 6:56 an example is shown where 7/9 pixels match (~78%) the output in the video is 55% which matches the cross-product method used but is nowhere near the 78% I expected.

Also, if a filter was looking for a location in an input where each pixel was 0 then using a cross product in the conv-layer would be of no use. Every output would be multiplied by 0 and so there would be no way to tell where the pattern occurred.

If anyone can tell me what I am missing that would be great!

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First, 7 pixels match and 2 are opposite. So you have (7-2)/9 which is 55%. It is a measure of how closely the feature matched the input, but it is not just the sum of matched over all comparisons (for example in the video you can have negative data).

I'm not sure about your second question. The output of a convolutional layer is feature maps. Each feature map is the results of convolving the previous layer with a specific filter. So each map of the output looks at more than just one location.

Still, almost always you have irrelevant parts of the input.